# The type initializer for 'Spheremark.ServiceManager' threw an exception.; Internal: Bad IL format.;

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, iis-8

i'm taking over a project where a developer used Spheremark as a service to talk to a RavenDB database (don't ask). The project is a .net core (2.0) Web API project and it works fine locally. However when I deploy it to my IIS on my virtual machine i get this error.

```
Error: The type initializer for 'Spheremark.ServiceManager' threw an exception.; Internal: Bad IL format.;
```

The method where the error hits is:

```
ServiceResult serviceResult = Spheremark.ServiceManager.InvokeService("SearchService", new Object[] { typeof(Role) });
```

I'm totally stuck with this, I can't find any information about Spheremark either so I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: Any time I've encountered `Internal: Bad IL format.` has been when trying to run code compiled for a newer CLR on an older version of the CLR. Could be that your server is a bit behind the times. Also might be worth switching the application pool "bitness" on your VM's IIS from 32 bit to 64 bit, or vice versa.

Comment: Hi Kev, thanks for your reply. I tried changing the app pool to enable 32 bit, but that didn't make any difference, which makes sense cuz it was all build for 64 anyway. I'm trying to think what i can do about this CLR version issue. When i check the Microsoft.NETCore.App folder, i see 2.0.9, locally i have apparently 4 (1.0.1, 2.0.7, 2.0.9 and 2.1.5), although my app is set as .net core 2.0. I would think that works. Also actually when i publish i set it as "Self-Contained", so i would think that just takes all the right dll's anyway, no? The VM is 2012, so i doubt that's the problem

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 is obsolete. Upgrade to 2.1 first, and see if you can reproduce this issue. Report to Microsoft and see what tips they provide, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues

Comment: I'm all out of ideas. I'd take @LexLi 's advice and upgrade to .net core 2.1 to see if that fixes this.